# Confused about te-form in a sentence

Tags: grammar

An example sentence for a new word I learned was:

> 徐々にホームシックを克服していってます

What is していってます? Why not just say しています? I understand that its te form of している, but what is the difference between these two?

Comment: *I understand that its te form of している* -- why do you understand it so? Does いる conjugate to いって?

Answer (score 4):

The いってます part of your sentence is the continuous form of the structure ～ていく.

Consider the difference between いて and いって.  These are the te-forms of いる and いく, respectively.  So the いってます part of your sentence

> 徐々にホームシックを克服して**いってます**

is actually ていく with the auxiliary いく itself being used in the te-form. The structure ～ていく refers to an action which has not yet been finished. In this case, the speaker is talking about a process of overcoming which is ongoing. Imagine it being used in other tenses:

> 克服していく　   I will overcome (by means of a process).
>   克服していった I overcame (by means of a process).
>   克服していっている　I am overcoming (still in the process).

By the way, even if いる and いく did share the exact same te-form, it still would not be correct to say いってます to describe a state. The idea of existence and being in a state is already conceptually contained within the verb いる. You don't need to put it in the te-form to describe states of being because it already does that job. But a verb like いく does not contain the same sense of state, which is why it needs the auxiliary いる.